# Execute a set of lines from another R file

Tags: r

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I'm looking for something similar to defining regions in R script. I would like to execute a pre-specified set of lines from another R script. I know I can run the entire file using `source(filename)` but instead of running the entire file, I would like to only run a few lines in the file.

Is it possible for me to define `regions` or anything similar in the file and then execute it from another file?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Seems you should be writing R functions and building packages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you're worried about the region of interest will be shifted once you add new lines upstream, then an alternative (or slightly modified) version of MrFlick's answer would be read as:

```
sourcePartial <- function(fn,startTag='#from here',endTag='#to here') {
  lines <- scan(fn, what=character(), sep="\n", quiet=TRUE)
  st<-grep(startTag,lines)
  en<-grep(endTag,lines)
  tc <- textConnection(lines[(st+1):(en-1)])
  source(tc)
  close(tc)
}
```

Now you need to put a small, unique hash tag just above and below of the region of interest. Such as "#from here" and "#to here"

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't sound like a super-safe idea given how easily line numbers can change during edits. Seems like it would be safest to split up your larger sourced file into smaller parts that are safer to include and run. But you could do something like this

```
sourcePartial <- function(fn, skip=0, n=-1) {
    lines <- scan(fn, what=character(), sep="\n", skip=skip, n=n, quiet=TRUE)
    tc <- textConnection(lines)
    source(tc)
    close(tc)
}
```

here we use `scan()` to read lines from a file. See the documentation for `skip=` and `n=` at `?scan` to see how to skip a certain number of lines and stop reading after a certain number. So

```
sourcePartial("test.R", 4, 11)
```

would run lines 5-15 from "test.R"

Comment: I suppose you could write something a bit more general if the poster were willing to break the source file up into sections with a common (commented) header label, say `#header: Region_4`, You could read with one pass to find the lines with headers and then pick out the target section based on name or sequence number.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think the generalized version is even better.

Comment: Well, if that's what you wanted it would have been better to describe that in the original question. The other version makes even more assumptions about file contents.