# Execute multiple sets of lines from another R file

Tags: r

I asked this before, but maybe I didn't ask exactly enough. 
I want to run from my Master-R file other, quite long R files. On the first glimpse that's easy to accomplish with `source()`.

The point is, they are so long, that I don't want to run all of them, just a certain part of it. Someone on my former post showed me this hidden [gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245554/execute-a-set-of-lines-from-another-r-file), but the both run from point A to point B.

What I want is to run from my file another file, starting at line x, then run to line x+z, skip a certain amount of rows, and then continue to run the same file from line y to y+z.

The solution in the link I attached is working and great, but I can't skip rows (This coding is above my skill), without creating another funtion and setting more start- and endpoints.

Is it possible to call something like this  `source(df.R, excludeLine(1:6, 20, 30:end)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a set of lines from another R file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245554/execute-a-set-of-lines-from-another-r-file)

Comment: You already asked the same question a couple of hours ago and it was flagged as duplicate

Comment: The answer of [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245818/4612235) to the linked question gives a good starting point for writing your own function to do this.

Comment: Yes, but the point is I want to exclude/ skip lines, not run from a to b. It's close, just the other way around.

Comment: From my own experience as a beginner: Don't do this. Learn how to break your code in functions and call the functions. This will save you from headaches in future.

Answer (score 0):

[Just slightly modifying this very excellent answer:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26246118/2706826) should work.

```
  sourcePartial <- function(fn,startTag1='#from here1',endTag1='#to here1', startTag2='#from here2',endTag2='#to here2') {
  lines <- scan(fn, what=character(), sep="\n", quiet=TRUE)
  st1<-grep(startTag1,lines)
  en1<-grep(endTag1,lines)
  st2<-grep(startTag2,lines)
  en2<-grep(endTag2,lines)
  tc <- textConnection(lines[c((st1+1):(en1-1),(st2+1):(en2-1))])
  source(tc)
  close(tc)
}
```

But really, just have a go yourself next time and you might learn...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm puzzled that this problem is uncommon.

Comment: It's really not a good way to program though. Just because you can do it, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Do you have a better idea for me? I see as only alternative to run source() and make Versions of my Scripts where I delete all I want to exclude.

Comment: I've no idea but your scripts sound messy. Think about this: http://r4ds.had.co.nz/functions.html

Comment: If you're a beginner, think about taking yourself through that whole book - it instills good practices